# How to autowire field in static @BeforeClass?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public void ITest {
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository dao;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        dao.save(initialEntity); //not possible as field is not static
    }
}
```

How can I have my service injected already in the static init class?

Comment: This blog post may help you - http://saltnlight5.blogspot.in/2012/09/enhancing-spring-test-framework-with.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks to me that you are trying to populate DB before tests.

I would give a try to two options:

- If you can extract initial scripts to sql file (if that is option for you without using repository bean) you can use [this approach](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/022-preload-database-execute-sql-spring-testing/) and annotate your test with `@Sql`
- You can explore [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) and here is [link to spring dbunit connector](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) which is doing exactly that and helping you populate DB before tests. Here is a [github link](https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/) for integrating between spring test framework and dbunit. After you do that you have `@DatabaseSetup` and `@DatabaseTearDown` which will do thing on DB you need

I know that this does not answer how to inject bean in static `@BeforeClass` but form code it looks it is solving your problem.

**Update:**
I recently run into same problem in my project and dug out [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/enhancing-spring-test) which helped me and I think it is elegant way of dealing with this type of problem. You can extend `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` with listener which can do instance level setup with all your defined beans.

Comment: The last link (in the last paragraph) is broken. What happens to be sad, as it seems to have interesting information, according to your explanation :(

Comment: @ElPiter, it was moved to https://dzone.com/articles/enhancing-spring-test

Answer (score 55):

With Junit 5 you can do this (@BeforeAll instead of @BeforeClass)

```
public void ITest {
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository dao;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(@Autowired EntityRepository dao) {
        dao.save(initialEntity); //possible now as autowired function parameter is used
    }
}
```

By leaving the field it means it can be used in other tests

Comment: `Non static field cannot be referenced from a static context...`

Comment: @Chris A, It is using the `dao` which is being passed as the parameter in init() method, not the class field`dao`. This works.

Answer (score 33):

One workaround that I have been using to get this working is to use `@Before` with a flag to skip it being executed for each testcase

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class BaseTest {

@Autowired
private Service1 service1;

@Autowired
private Service2 service2;

private static boolean dataLoaded = false;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    if (!dataLoaded) {
        service1.something();
        service2.somethingElse();
        dataLoaded = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep doing this, but there really has to be a better way, especially, when you're relying on an injected/autowired field, because in that case `@BeforeClass` will not work.

Comment: What about the @AfterClass part after the execution of your tests.  Any strategy to keep it simple as this first part?

Comment: @emecas do the same thing as the post mention, but use `@After` instead of `@Before`, and each time it's called, you update a test counter, when the test counter goes to your last test, execute your statement.

Comment: The biggest problem with that approach is to do the same workaround with @After annotation.  In order to do that it is mandatory to know the number of tests dynamically.

Answer (score 13):

UPD for Spring 2.x versions.

Spring 2.x supports new feature a `SpringExtension` for Junit 5 Jupiter, where all you have to do is:

1. Declare your test class with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`
2. Inject your `@BeforeAll` (replacement for `@BeforeClass` in JUnit 5) with the bean

For example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
...
public void ITest {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(@Autowired EntityRepository dao) {
        dao.save(initialEntity);
    }

}
```

Assuming you correctly configured JUnit 5 Jupiter with Spring 2.x

More about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-extension

Comment: That sounds promising!

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question we should recap Spring 2.x versions.

If you want to "autowire" a bean in your `@BeforeTest` class you can use the `ApplicationContext` interface. Let's see an example:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        EntityRepository dao2 = (EntityRepository) context.getBean("dao");
        List<EntityRepository> all = dao2.getAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull(all);
    }
```

What's happening: using the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` we are instantiating all beans contained in the `application-context.xml` file.

With `context.getBean()` we read the bean specified (it must match the name of the bean!); and then you can use it for your initialization.

You should give to the bean another name (that's the `dao2`!) otherwise Spring normal "autowired" cannot work on the predefined bean.

As a side note, if your test extends `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` you can do some initialization using `executeSqlScript(sqlResourcePath, continueOnError)`; method, so you don't depend on a class/method that you also have to test separately.

Comment: I cannot instantiate the `ApplicationContext` myself as I also use `@IntegrationTest` to autowire my normal `@EnableAutoConfiguration` classes during test (annotation based config).

Comment: Why don't you use the `executeSqlScript` then ? It is a static method that you get for free when you extend the `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` class.

Comment: The question is of course just an example. I could as well have to execute any logic in @BeforeClass, not only database initialization...

Comment: I think that in static methods you can only call static variables. So the best thing to do is create a Service with static methods that perform your logic. For example, you can create a Service that autowires stuff, and static getters that return autowired classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use some DB data in your tests, you could also mock the repository and use the [@Before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42261965/2049986) workaround Narain Mittal describes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public void ITest {
    @MockBean
    private EntityRepository dao;

    @Before
    public static void init() {
        when(dao.save(any())).thenReturn(initialEntity);
    }
}
```